# Dynamic programming: Balanced Partition

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to implement a dynamic programming algorithm for this problem:
Input: A given arrangement S of non-negative numbers {S1.......Sn}

we want to partition S into 2 subset S1 an S2 and minimize |sum(S1)-sum(S2)|, then partition the 2 subset in the same way ,  we stop when we reach  an Subset with 2 or 1 element ()We must preserve the order of S elements).

example : S= {1,2,2,3,4} Output { { {1,2}{2} } {3,4} }

With the help of [this article](http://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBAfl/VT06/algorithms/BOOK/BOOK2/NODE45.HTM)  this is my implementation :

```
static String partition(int s[], int db,int fn)
{
    int n = (fn-db) +1;
    String res ="";
    if (n<=2){
        res +="[";
        for(int l =db ;l<=fn;l++) res+=s[l];
        res +="]";
        return res;
    }
    int[][] m= new int [n+1][3];                 /* DP table for values */             
    int[][] d= new int [n+1][3];                 /* DP table for dividers */ 
    int [] p = new int [n+1];                    /* prefix sums array */
    int cost;                               /* test split cost */
    int i,x = 0;                              /* counters */

    p[0] = 0;                               /* construct prefix sums */
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) 
        p[i]=p[i-1]+s[(db-1)+i];

    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) 
        m[i][1] = p[i];    /* initialize boundaries */
        m[1][2] = s[db];


    for (i=2; i<=n; i++){                    /* evaluate main recurrence */
            m[i][2] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (x=1; x<=(i-1); x++) {
                cost = Math.max(m[x][1], p[i]-p[x]);
                if (m[i][2] > cost) {
                    m[i][2] = cost;
                    d[i][2] = db+(x-1);
                }
            }
     }
    return res +="["+partition(s,db,d[n][2])+partition(s,d[n][2]+1,fn)+"]";

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int []set ={2,1,1,1,5};
    System.out.print(partition(set,0,set.length-1));
}
```

1. Is my implementation is the good one or there is another dynamic programing solution whitout recursive call ?
2. I cannot calculate complexity of this algorithm , I try to use Master theorem T(n)=aT(nb)+f(n) , but I don't now n/b  the size of each subproblem for the 2 recursive call.

   3.How we can do the same partition if we can change the order of element ?

Comment: I don't quite understand how your problem description fits the example. For `{1,2,2,3,4}` a partition `S1={2,3,1}`, `S2={4,2}` would yield a difference of `0`, which is better than a difference of `1`.

Comment: the partition must respect the order of initial array S.

Comment: As you have code here, you should tag language.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way: in the worst case, you have an array where each index i contains the value 2<sup>i</sup>. In this case, the split only decreases the length by one, meaning your recursion depth is linear in n. At each level, you do O(n) work, so the total complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>). Fortunately, such arrays will be very short in practice, because we generally do not consider such huge numbers, so the real-world performance will generally be better. When the weights are somewhat balanced, you should have O(n log n) performance.

As for the first question, I'm not sure what you mean with "the good one".

EDIT: You algorithm could be made more efficient by performing a binary search on the location you want to split the array at. This is possible because the order must be preserved.

Comment: Thinks for your answer ;
by The good one i mean : DP solution without recursive call.

Comment: Well, you obviously _do_ have two recursive calls in your code.